# Webpack generates arrow function in ES5

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecma

I want to use TypeScript modules and bundle them via Webpack. Here are my config files:

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        entry: './index.ts',
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }],
        },
    };
};
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es3"
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**/*", "webpack.config.js"]
}
```

Maybe I got something wrong from the documentation. The aim was to generate code in ES5 (or even earlier). But here is my bundled file:

```js
(()=>{var n=function(n,o){console.warn(o)};n(0,0),n(0,1)})();
```

It has an arrow function, which was added in ES6. I am confused. How can I get rid of that?

---

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I try to compile:

```js
const func = (foo, bar: number) => {
    console.warn(bar);
};

func(0, 0);
func(2, 1);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Also, I run the compilation process in production mode. (idk, maybe that's useful information)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly I want to have. But I can't understand what am I doing wrong. I added the code

Comment: did you set target to es5 as described in webpack.config https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The decision is simply adding `target: ['web', 'es5']` to your webpack configuration.

You could also set `target: 'es5'`, but in this case, there are some problems. At least in my case without specifying 'web' TerserWebpackPlugin refused to compress files in the production mode.

Comment: It's important to note, that the webpack `target` option is ment, not the typescript `target` option.

Comment: This solved my issue, I was getting arrow function in my output with just 'es5' adding 'web' solved my issue

Answer (score 4):

That's the problem I faced last week after upgrading the webpack to version 5.

By default, it's bundling it as ES6. In your webpack configuration, configuring `output.environment` should resolve the problem.

**Edit: webpack only change it's internal usages with these configurations.**

[webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment](http://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment)

**It does not compile the modules. For the module compilation, babel should be used.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The version of webpack is `5.3.2`. But adding `environment: 5` causes an error `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.`

Comment: It's weird, I just tried, and yes, saw the same error.

Comment: Ok, I just realized the environment option only manages internal usage of webpack. It does not compile your modules. For doing it, you should use babel transformer plugin.

This is how you configure only webpack itself.,
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment

Comment: I have `ts-loader`. It can handle modules. Also just getting rid of arrow function is seems to be a crutch. Because not only arrow function were added in ES6