# Why does webpack 5 bundle includes non typescript target features such as arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Im trying to compile following code:

```js
// src/index.tsx
console.log(() => {})
```

When I use `"target": "es6"` in `tsconfig` I get following code (all ok):

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log((()=>{}))})();
```

But when I use `"target": "es3"` in `tsconfig` **the generated code still contains SOME arrow functions** (that arent supported in ES3):

```
(()=>{"use strict";console.log((function(){}))})();
```

What's the point of transpiling just my code but not the own webpack generated one?

This is my webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "webpackbundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack generates arrow function in ES5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620341/webpack-generates-arrow-function-in-es5)

Comment: The solution of that question is not supported in webpack 5

Comment: this is the [answer you want I think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64622063/542251)

Comment: You are right, I was adding the suggested configuration to tsconfig instead of webpack. The second response confused me